# In the phrase Omnimoda potestate Antistes, should any of the words be capitalized?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin

In the phrase *omnimoda potestate antistes*, should any words be capitalized? And how would it be translated? It is in reference to a 16th century bishop  who considered himself, *omnimoda potestate antistes*.

Answer (score 1):

*Antistes* literally means something like "stander before", from *ante* "before, in front of" and *stare* "to stand", and usually means "overseer" (compare *president*, literally "sitter before", from *prae* "before" and *sedēre* "to sit"), but in the context of Christianity it's a title that's either usually left untranslated or (more commonly in the Catholic Church, I think) translated as "bishop".

*Omnimodā potestāte* is the ablative of *omnimoda potestās* (the macrons are not usually written, but I've added them so you can see *omnimodā* has a long *a* in the ablative but not the nominative), the "authority of all kinds". The use of the ablative here is kind of unusual but suggests to me that his position as *antistes* comes forth *out of* the authority of all of kinds, which would presumably be God or the Church. (If it's an instrumental ablative, on the other hand, he's assigning *himself*, or rather the office  of *antistes*, authority of all kinds, which seems a bit brazen.)

The whole construction can be translated as "bishop of the authority of all kinds". As for how it should be capitalised, the Catholic Encyclopedia seems to use ***O**mnimoda **p**otestate **A**ntistes*, which I see no real reason to contradict.

Comment: Googling around a bit, I noticed that, while this title seems to be unique, the title *vicaria potestate antistes* is found a few times in historical sources, which *may* be a fancy term for "vicar general" - in which case *antistes* does not mean "bishop". It is possible that this title was modeled after that.